# Efficient way of converting Minute data to Hourly in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time, time-series

I have a database with several million datapoints of stock data which each are in minute data, so i want to convert this to hourly data with an sql query. The features i have available for each point is:
open, close, high, low, volume, time.

My intuition about the solution is that the data should be divided in chucks of 60 sorted by time. Open and Close is the First and Last in the divided data. High and Low is the max and min, and volume is sum. This should create a new point the should be equivalent to the hourly data.

This is very simple to do in code and only takes a couple seconds, but i would like to do it in sql.

I have managed to make query that works, but it is very slow.
Here i create a query grouped that returns the data with new id, i later group these points on that id, the identifier is just the company i am querying for.

```
with grouped as (select
    (mod(id, 60) + id)/60 as id_group,
    close,
    high,
    low,
    open,
    volume
    from stock
    where identifier = 15611 order by time asc)
```

Here i select the features i would like in my result.

```
select 
    max(high),
    min(low),
    (select close from (select close, id_group from grouped) as closer where closer.id_group = grouped.id_group limit 1),
    (select open from (select open, id_group from grouped order by id_group desc) as closer where closer.id_group = grouped.id_group limit 1),
    sum(volume)
from grouped
group by id_group
```

I realise that the problem is probably the way i handle close and open, but i could not figure out a better way. It takes around 2 minutes to query which seems like a lot.

Is there a more correct way os doing this that would not result in such a bad runtime?

Comment: Do you want to treat hours as integer or as a sort of quasi-floating point quantity?

Comment: Not totally sure what you are asking, but im gonna assume you are referring to the input were i have just written 60 as an integer.  If im correct then yes it should be treated as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed your queries. You must set some performance solutions for your queries.

1. After PostgreSQL version 12 `with` statement default using `non materialized` mode. PostgreSQL to decided let users manually control `materialized` mode for using `CTE`. So that, you can set materialized for the best performance on `with` statements. When you use `materialized` then your queries which wrote inside the `with` statements will be executed one time and in other times DB will be used the only result of queries.

*P.S. You have used the `grouped` query many times in your second query.*

2. You can create your own function for converting minutes to hours (`mod(id, 60) + id)/60`), and after then create a function-based index, expression index by using this function. Because in your second query you used this condition (`where closer.id_group`) on the `where` statement and grouped this field. But DB can not use indexes for these conditions.
3. Check your indexes list for table `stock`. For this table, you must create a minimum of two indexes for fields `identifier` and `time`.